# Facebook integration compatibility issue

Tags: iphone, facebook

I m creating app for iPhone.
when user click share button detail displayed on screen are shared on facebook.
I want my application to be work on both iOS 5 and iOS 6.
Right now I have used facebook SDK 3.1.
It is working fine with iOS 6 but not for iOS 5.
It is giving this error:

```
2012-10-29 12:39:49.588 FacebookDemo[1715:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBSession: an attempt was made reauthorize 
permissions on an unopened session'
```

I think it is problem with some framework which require by facebook SDK like social.framework which are not available in iOS 5

what should I do to work this on iOS 5 and 6 both?

Answer (score 2):

Generally you need beside FacebookSDK also AdSupport,Social and Accounts frameworks which are needed to be set to Optional since Accounts is only avaliable in IOs 5 and the other two is new in IOS 6

actually it is not realted with the backcompatibility.
You get 
    FBSession: an attempt was made reauthorize permissions on an unopened session
when you want to make a new request when the session state is not open.
MAke sure you before eacj request.

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

//MAke you request 

}else{
//REopen your session
}
```

Comment: Yes I have already done. If I have not done how it work on iOS 6!

Comment: I think problem is in openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions method. it return YES but completionHandler never executed.

Comment: you know which request is exactly causing this problem.can you debug?

Comment: yes i have debug and found that completionHandler block of openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions is not called. even if this method is returning YES. this block call method "sessionStateChanged" I have implemented this method from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/ so u can see my code there it is same.